# Find percentage and rounding it two places

Tags: c#, ambiguous

I know this is basic one I'm asking, bear with me.

I'm trying to find out the percentage.

This is what I'm trying, but it is giving me an error of ambiguous call.

```
int total = 1;
int totalUsers = 3;
if (totalUsers > 0)
{
    var per =Math.Round(total / totalUsers,4) * 100 ;
    object[] args = new object[] { total, totalUsers, per };
    lblMsg.Text = string.Format("{0} of {1} users already voted({2}%)", args);
}
```

```
For Example:
if total = 1
totalusers = 3 
per should be after rounding of 33.33%
```

Comment: What are the compile-time types of `total` and `totalUsers`? And why are you creating an object with the results? What is the *exact* error message? (Don't answer these questions in a comment - edit your question.)

Comment: where are you getting `ambiguous call` error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve the `ambiguous call` error, change to:

```
var per =Math.Round((decimal)total / totalUsers,4) * 100 ;
```

Comment: As per my above example per is 33.33 but when i pass this to string.format it is making per as 33.3300% , Any suggestions.

Comment: you can control that part in the string format like using `{2:N2}`

Comment: it is giving error "Input string was not in a correct format" when i made this change.

Comment: @dotNETbeginner it won't work as you would get only `33` (it evaluates to 0.33 when you say 2 decimal places)

Comment: @L.B is there any work around to avoid this extra zeros that are appended in string.format.

Comment: @ankur see the  V4Vendetta's comment. use `"{0} of {1} users already voted({2:N2}%)"`

Comment: @L.B see my below comment of V4Vendetta's  it is giving an error.

Comment: I have corrected that one if the round off is giving an whole number lets say 80 , it is adding 80.00 % can this be avoided.

Comment: @ankur your question changed from `ambiguous call` to `how to format a string`. Try this `"{0} of {1} users already voted({2:##.##}%)"`